# PSU power cable length, and will my graphics card fit in my case?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building, cable, gpu, case

I've decided to build a computer, this will be the first computer that I've built but I've done lots of research and have a list of parts which I will be ordering. I asked for someone to check my component list, to make sure that they are compatible, and the only problem was, that as the PSU is mounted at the bottom of the case and I have chosen a micro ATX motherboard the power cables may not be long enough to reach the components on the motherboard.

[My motherboard is an Asus M5A78L-M](http://www.ebuyer.com/269072-asus-m5a78l-m-usb3-amd-socket-am3-8-channel-hd-audio-matx-motherboard-m5a78l-m-usb3)

[My case, a Casecom 6788 (or Rosewill Challenger in America)](http://www.ebuyer.com/172779-casecom-6788-all-black-case-km-6788-black)

[And my PSU a Corsair 600W CX Series V2](http://www.ebuyer.com/269259-corsair-600w-cx-series-v2-psu-6x-sata-2x-pci-e-cmpsu-600cxv2uk)

The PSU [manual](http://www.corsair.com/media/cms/manual/49-000036_rev_AA_CXv2Manual.pdf) says that the cables are:

```
ATX Cable - 600mm
CPU Cable - 600mm
2 PCI-E Cables - 600mm
2 SATA Cables - 550mm
Peripheral Cable - 1050mm
```

The dimentions for the case are 473mm, Width 190mm, Height 433.8mm. I would imagine that the cables would be long enough, but as I mentioned, I've never built a computer before so I would apreciate input from someone with more experience with this sort of thing.

My other problem is that some people have said that smaller graphics cards do not fit in the case. The graphics card I have chosen is a [Radeon HD 6770](http://www.ebuyer.com/266983-asus-hd-6770-1gb-gddr5-direct-cu-dvi-vga-hdmi-pci-e-graphics-eah6770-dc-2di-1gd5).

Thanks in advance. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [your case](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811147153) on newegg, and if you click the images it shows additional shots of the inside.

It looks to me like everything should fit in there fine.  I have a [Lian Li](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811112103) case that the PSU mounts on the bottom like that, and the cables are annoyingly long in most instances.  My case is a mid tower as well, so with power connectors of that length you should be fine.

I would think that extra long video cards might present an issue because of the arrangement of the drive bays and HDD racks, but a short length card should present no issues. I have a [GTX 460](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121390) in my current machine, and it fits, but anything longer would be pressing my luck.

My card is 9.5 inches (241mm) long and the case is 15 inches (381mm), so I would imagine your configuration should fit.

Comment: Thanks. That helps, I misread the forum post, thought he was saying that some graphics cards would be too small. Is your motherboard atx or micro atx?

Comment: It is an ATX sized motherboard.